# Transform option value to link - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this Javascript that transforms select input to `ul` and options to `li`. The `option value="something"` becomes `li rel="something"`.

Example:

```
This:
<select><opion value="something">Some text</option></select>

It becomes this:
<ul><li rel="something">Some text</li></ul>
```

How can I transform `option value="something"` to `<li><a href="something">some text</a>` using this code? I had some issues and I can not do it. Someone can help me?

```
$('select').each(function () {
  var $this = $(this), numberOfOptions = $(this).children('option').length;

  $this.addClass('select-hidden');
  $this.wrap('<div class="select"></div>');
  $this.after('<div class="select-styled"></div>');

  var $styledSelect = $this.next('div.select-styled');
  $styledSelect.text($this.children('option').eq(0).text());

  var $list = $('<ul />', {
    'class': 'select-options'
  }).insertAfter($styledSelect);

  for (var i = 0; i < numberOfOptions; i++) {
    $('<li />', {
      text: $this.children('option').eq(i).text(),
      rel: $this.children('option').eq(i).val()
    }).appendTo($list);
  }

  var $listItems = $list.children('li');

  $styledSelect.click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('div.select-styled.active').not(this).each(function () {
      $(this).removeClass('active').next('ul.select-options').hide();
    });
    $(this).toggleClass('active').next('ul.select-options').toggle();
  });

  $listItems.click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $styledSelect.text($(this).text()).removeClass('active');
    $this.val($(this).attr('rel'));
    $list.hide();
  });

  $(document).click(function () {
    $styledSelect.removeClass('active');
    $list.hide();
  });
});
```

Code in Jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/felipeemarcon/c8pouz8s/3/

Thanks.

Comment: what are the issues you met?

Comment: It seems work properly.

Comment: @Sphinx I do not know how to do that.

Comment: @Isitea Yes, the way it works works great. But I need the `option` to become a link. Like this- `<li><a href="something">some text</a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the code around a bit...

```
$('select').each(function () {
  var $this = $(this), numberOfOptions = $(this).children('option').length;

  $this.addClass('select-hidden');
  $this.wrap('<div class="select"></div>');
  $this.after('<div class="select-styled"></div>');

  var $styledSelect = $this.next('div.select-styled');
  $styledSelect.text($this.children('option').eq(0).text());

  var $list = $('<ul />', {
    'class': 'select-options'
  }).insertAfter($styledSelect);

  for (var i = 0; i < numberOfOptions; i++) {
    let $a = $('<a />', {
      href: $this.children('option').eq(i).val(),
      text: $this.children('option').eq(i).text()
    });
    let $li = $('<li />');
    $a.appendTo($li);
    $li.appendTo($list);
  }

  var $listItems = $list.children('li');

  $styledSelect.click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('div.select-styled.active').not(this).each(function () {
      $(this).removeClass('active').next('ul.select-options').hide();
    });
    $(this).toggleClass('active').next('ul.select-options').toggle();
  });

  $listItems.click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $styledSelect.text($(this).text()).removeClass('active');
    $this.val($(this).attr('rel'));
    $list.hide();
  });

  $(document).click(function () {
    $styledSelect.removeClass('active');
    $list.hide();
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4x2yvs3L/

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```js
$('select').each(function () {
  var $this = $(this), numberOfOptions = $(this).children('option').length;

  $this.addClass('select-hidden');
  $this.wrap('<div class="select"></div>');
  $this.after('<div class="select-styled"></div>');

  var $styledSelect = $this.next('div.select-styled');
  $styledSelect.text($this.children('option').eq(0).text());

  var $list = $('<ul />', {
    'class': 'select-options'
  }).insertAfter($styledSelect);

  for (var i = 0; i < numberOfOptions; i++) {
    
    $('<a />', {
      text: $this.children('option').eq(i).text(),
      href: $this.children('option').eq(i).val()
    }).appendTo($('<li />').appendTo($list));
    /*
    $('<li />', {
      text: $this.children('option').eq(i).text(),
      rel: $this.children('option').eq(i).val()
    }).appendTo($list);
    */

  }

  var $listItems = $list.children('li');

  $styledSelect.click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('div.select-styled.active').not(this).each(function () {
      $(this).removeClass('active').next('ul.select-options').hide();
    });
    $(this).toggleClass('active').next('ul.select-options').toggle();
  });

  $listItems.click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $styledSelect.text($(this).text()).removeClass('active');
    $this.val($(this).attr('rel'));
    $list.hide();
  });

  $(document).click(function () {
    $styledSelect.removeClass('active');
    $list.hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
<option value="something 1">Some text 1</option>
<option value="something 2">Some text 2</option>
<option value="something 3">Some text 3</option>
<option value="something 4">Some text 4</option>
</select>
```

```
$('<li />', {
  text: $this.children('option').eq(i).text(),
  rel: $this.children('option').eq(i).val()
}).appendTo($list);
```

This part makes `<li>` from `<option>`.

So it is changed as follows, to make `<a>`.

```
$('<a />', {
  text: $this.children('option').eq(i).text(),
  href: $this.children('option').eq(i).val()
}).appendTo($('<li />').appendTo($list));
```